# Applying Labels to objects within a Multidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and would like to place labels in front of the eye color for example "Eye Color: brown". The problem is I don't know how to access the nested array in a loop to place the labels next to each eye color. I know how to  access the information in the array(s) for example `people[0][3][0] = "blue";` to change the first person's eye color.

**I apologize for the confusion. I am following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cta5s1QBD8E and the instructor at 9:44 states using the for in loop you can add labels for hair and eye color.**

```
var people = [
  [ "James", 60, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Patricia", 55, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Patrice", 22, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Montrell", 32, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ]
];
//people[0][3][0] = "pink";

// for loop that interates through people array   
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    // writes the Person and number header
     document.write("<h2>Person " + (i+1) + "</h2>");
   // loops through each person and writes their information
   for(var details in people[i]) {
       document.write(people[i][details] + "<br>");
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear. There are two values in your nested array ("brown" and "black"). So, Which one you represent eye color? first item (0-index)??

Comment: Do you need to convert an existing array to an object or do you not know how to use objects?

Comment: " people[0][3][0] = "blue"; to change the first person's eye color. " I'd like to put a label in front each persons eye colors

Comment: @user3574939 arrays do not support labels. If you want labeled properties you have to use an object rather than an array. See my answer below.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I am following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cta5s1QBD8E and the instructor at 9:44 states using the for in loop you can add labels for hair and eye color.

Comment: No confusion chill..!! updated my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var people = [
  [ "James", 60, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Patricia", 55, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Patrice", 22, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Montrell", 32, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ]
];
//people[0][3][0] = "pink";

// for loop that interates through people array
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
// writes the Person and number header
 document.write("<h2>Person " + (i+1) + "</h2>");
   // loops through each person and writes their information
   for(var details in people[i]) {

   //checking if the current item under iteration is an object
   //if it is, it would be the ["brown", "black"] aray, then print
   //people[i][details][0] as hair color and people[i][details][1] as eye color
   if(typeof people[i][details] == "object") {
   document.write("hair color is "+ people[i][details][0] + "<br>");
   document.write("eye color is "+ people[i][details][1] + "<br>");
    }
    else{
         //the current item is either a name, age or country, of either String or Number type
          document.write(people[i][details] + "<br>");
         }

   }
}
```

Provided the structure of the array is uniform and the `array` of eyes is the fourth item in your each object in people array.

Please read the comment above the last `for` loop if you have any confusion.

Well it is ok to have arrays like this if your goal is to learn to iterate over multi dimensional arrays but an object structure as the other answer has suggested would be an ideal way to keep data in future.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I am following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cta5s1QBD8E and the instructor at 9:44 states using the for in loop you can add labels for hair and eye color.

Comment: @user3574939 updated my answer! have mentioned comments to make it understandable. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You really should be using objects rather than arrays e.g.

```
var people = [
  { 
    name : "James", 
    age : 60,
    country: "United States",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    hairColor: "black"
  },
  ...
];
```

An array is defined with square brackets [] and is just an ordered list. An object is defined with curly braces {} and is a dictionary of key value pairs.

```
var james = people[0];
```

That will give you the first person in the people array. Then to get the eyeColor:

```
var color = james.eyeColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a conversion, to convert the existing people array data to an object:

```
var people = [
  [ "James", 60, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Patricia", 55, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Patrice", 22, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ],
  [ "Montrell", 32, "United States", ["brown", "black"] ]
];

 for (var i = 0; i < people.length;  i++){
    var details = {};
    details.eyeColor = people[i][3][0];
    details.hairColor = people[i][3][1];
    people[i][3] = details;
    people[i].splice(4,1);
}
```

...

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I am following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cta5s1QBD8E and the instructor at 9:44 states using the for in loop you can add labels for hair and eye color.